# Как хранить много текста в java

Tags: java

Здраствуйте, я хочу сделать программу которая работает с рецептами , но я не знаю как мне их хранить и использовать, если использовать txt файлы то тогда во что их хранить в программе без базы данных.

Comment: H2 файловая sql база для java и на java http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: https://fooobar.com/questions/7116979/how-should-i-store-text-files-in-a-java-program-to-easily-read-them Хранение файлов в программе

Comment: это выглядит примерно так: хочу построить дом. не знаю, как мне привезти много песка... даже если песок начнет сыпаться с неба  и его будет реально много, боюсь, что это будет не главная и далеко не единственная проблема))

Comment: Используй папирус или бересту

Answer (score 0):

храните в Java Resources.

```
Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("receipts.txt")
```